# Regex to match 2 words, one of which is mandatory, other optional but after matching a third word which is located after the previous two

Tags: regex, pcre

I got stuck at the following regex:

Suppose I have three words: `foo`, `bar` and `woo`.

If I match `woo` I need to find at least the previous closest `foo` (mandatory) which must be before the current `woo` I matched and the closest to `woo`.
Optionally, if there's a closest `bar` before `woo`, I need to match it too.

E.g. the chunks:

```
...
3218 9839201 39021 foo 389201 83902 10321
832091 83902 321890 bar 382910 9382 19832 19
woo
...
```

and:

```
...
3218 9839201 39021 bar 389201 83902 10321
832091 83902 321890 foo 382910 9382 19832 19
woo
...
```

are OK, but:

```
...
3218 woo 9839201 39021 bar 389201 83902 10321
832091 83902 321890 foo 382910 9382 19832 19
...
```

Is not.

How can I explain this using regular expressions?

I tried using lookaheads https://regex101.com/r/3b4dpu/3, but I do not know how can I match the closest `bar` before `woo`.

Thank you for the attention!

**EDIT**: I will try to be more clear and clarify better what I need to do:

1. For any `woo` in a multiline text or single line string, I need to match the last `foo` before that `woo`.
   If there's a also `bar` before that same `woo` which can be either before that `foo` or after that `foo` I want to capture it (it's optional but if there is, I need it).
   For `bar` I also need the last `bar` before that `woo` I matched before. ;

   https://regex101.com/r/3b4dpu/5 Here I can effectively match the last `foo` before a `woo` using lookaheads, simply by searching for `foo`. But I also need to match a `bar` before or after that `foo` which in turn is before that `woo` and this `bar` should be the last `bar` before that `woo`. How can I do that?
2. This would be the next step, but for now it would be ok to complete the first one... After all `woo`s have been matched with their corresponding `foo` and optional `bar` before/after that `foo` but not after that `woo` (please note that the case where there isn't any `woo` is also ok), I would need to match any `foo` which could have this time an optional `bar` **before** that `foo`...

Hope this clarifies my question further, please look at the regex101 link!

Comment: Your description is unclear. I suspect this is an XY problem: What are you actually trying to do and why are you using a regex?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/3vagrF/3

Comment: No it doesn't, because it matches `woo` preceded by `bar` but doesn't match `foo` (`foo` is mandatory and should be before the nth matched `woo`, `bar` is optional)

Comment: Probably https://regex101.com/r/3b4dpu/6 will help.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is very close to PCRE and my regex doesn't use anything that is different between them, so I'm using JavaScript because it allows a live demo here.

```js
function check(what) {
  alert(what.innerText.match(RegExp(document.getElementById("regex").value, "m")));
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Click on a block to run the regex against it. 
The matching text (or else "null") will appear in an alert popup.</p>

<input type="text" id="regex" style="font-family:monospace;width:90%"
  value="\bfoo\b[\s\S]*?\bwoo\b"/>

<pre onclick="check(this)">...
3218 9839201 39021 foo 389201 83902 10321
832091 83902 321890 bar 382910 9382 19832 19
woo
...</pre>

<pre onclick="check(this)">...
3218 9839201 39021 bar 389201 83902 10321
832091 83902 321890 foo 382910 9382 19832 19
woo
...</pre>

<pre onclick="check(this)">...
3218 woo 9839201 39021 bar 389201 83902 10321
832091 83902 321890 foo 382910 9382 19832 19
...</pre>
</body>
```

This looks for the word "foo" (as delimited by word break characters in `\bfoo\b`), then any amount of characters (`[\s\S]` is a convenient way of matching anything, while `.` sometimes gets stuck on whether it can match newlines), but non-greedily (`*?` rather than `*` to make the shortest valid match), then the word "woo" via `\bwoo\b`.  The `/m` flag says the regex should be run against multiple lines at once.

[Here it is again](https://regex101.com/r/XmQUl6/1), with a descriptive walk through the regex and a better illustration of what matches, over at regex101.

You also requested:

> Optionally, if there's a closest `bar` before `woo`, I need to match it too.

This doesn't make much sense to me, since you get a match either way.  If you want to know whether you captured a `bar` then run the results through a second regex. ... unless you're saying it's `foo` *or* `bar`, in which case you'd want `/\b(?:foo|bar)\b[\s\S]*?\bwoo\b/m`.